# BQ Loader - Multiple Service Account

Tags: shell, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, command-line-interface, service-accounts

I need a support to understand how I can use the following command:

- bq show
- bq load

in my shell script using 2 different service account dynamically.

At the moment I didn't find any solution and I notice that the command connect to the current active account, so the only way is to switch every time between the 2 account, but for me is not a suitable solution.

The goal is to load a file into dedicated table specifying the SA that can access on this table

Could you please support me?

Details:

- Last gcloud CLI
- 2 Service Account
- 2 JSON file for authentication (one for each service accounts)

Best Regards

Simone

Comment: Please edit your question to show the commands you use and explain why they do not solve your problem. The `bq` command uses Application Default Credentials (ADC) generated by the CLI `gcloud`. You can switch the service account used by the CLI with the command `gcloud auth activate-service-account`. https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/activate-service-account

Comment: Why do you need 2 service accounts?